# Where can I find IP fragmented Sample pcaps for WireShark?

Tags: tcp, ip, wireshark, fragmentation

Are there any sources where I can find different pcaps samples for IP fragmented data (WireShark compatible)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Wireshark Sample Captures wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures) and search for fragments... for instance, they have the [Teardrop overlapping IP fragment attack](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=teardrop.cap)

Sending that to PCs would lock up an unpatched Windows 95 machine...

### EDIT

If you want to see general IP fragmentation, I can't think of a capture offhand, but you can simulate IP fragmentation with [creative use of tcprewrite](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/wiki/tcprewrite#DealingwithMTUproblems) under *nix.

Comment: @Mike, thanks. I already looked at that one but I wonder if there are more comprehensive samples somwhere

Comment: @Wajih, when you say comprehensive, what additional data points are you looking for?

Comment: @Mike, like IP fragmentation of FTP data, images, files etc. Which are then reconstructed by WireShark.

Comment: @Wajih, do you have access to a linux machine?

Comment: @Mike, Ubuntu is the best I got

Comment: @Wajih, nothing wrong with Ubuntu... check out my edit.  If you're willing to rewrite a pcap, then `tcprewrite` will allow you to see what normal IP fragmentation looks like.  Just feed it any FTP transfer and it will fragment at whatever IP mtu you specify.

Comment: @Wajih, sure thing... I use debian, so it is the `tcpreplay` package... I'm not sure what Ubuntu does, but usually they have the same package names...

Answer (score 5):

See the files attached to the following Wireshark bug reports for examples of IP fragmentation.

I would note that IP fragmentation is IP fragmentation regardless of the 
payloads carried over IP;

What are you looking for that you wish to see "IP fragmentation of FTP data, images, files, etc" ?

Is it actually TCP re-assembly that you wish to look at ?

[Bug 2651: sas.cap](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=2651)

[Bug 713: nfs_udp.pcap](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=713)